# Configurable And Simple Products Imported But Not Associated

Tags: magento2

My import works with no errors, my configurable product has all of the simple products' SKUs in the associated product sku field.

The products are all added, but the simple products do not appear in the configurable product.

I am trying to do something like this in configurable_variations field:

sku=shirt-black,color=Black,style=Medium|sku=shirt-red,color=Red,style=Medium

Comment: Better to add example file and version of Magento.

Comment: It happens to me when the SKU of the configurable product is an integer, if it contains letters, everything works fine. It used to work in 2.0.7, the "bug" is in 2.1

Comment: Did you check if the links are created in the `catalog_product_super_link` table ?

Comment: please share your a CSV with me.

Answer (score 1):

same issue and it was fixed by just making sure that the configurables were listed under all the simple products. not intuitive but here is a guide someone wrote and it seemed to work for me.
https://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2016/01/magento-2-import-configurable-products/

Answer (score 1):

I have been wrestling with this issue for hours, and in my case it was caused by the fact that my sku values in the original site had leading zeros. These were being dropped in the export file in the sku column , but were still present in the configurable variations field eg sku=0369,container_size=10 kg|sku=0370,container_size=23 kg

but the simple products, by now in the csv file had sku of 369 and 370 respectively, hence no match.

Seems obvious once you spot it!